# Set title by dynamically loaded AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently parse some AJAX that I load with this script:

```
function parseScript(_source) {
    var source = _source;
    var scripts = source.match(/<script[^>]*src=[^>]*>/g);
    if (scripts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        src = scripts[i].match(/src=("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/);
        src = src[2] || src[3];
        if (src) {
            addScriptTag(src);
        }
    }
    }
    var scripts = new Array();

    return source;
}
```

I have been trying to find the title and add it before the current title like "Loaded page title - Loading page title" experimenting a bit with `<title>` matches but still no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why regex instead of `getElementsByTagName("script")` and then `element.getAttribute("src")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the title with this code using jQuery

```
$('title').text('new title text goes here');
```

Is that what you wanted or were you looking for how to find the title in the source sent to the parseScript function?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be much easier without RegEx:

```
function parseScript() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var src = scripts[i].src;
        if(src) {
            addScriptTag(src);
        }
    }
}
```